# Python multiprocessing - Why does pool.close() take so long to return?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Sometimes a call to the function `pool.close()` takes a lot of time to return, and I want to understand why. Typically, I would have each process return a big `set` or a big `dict`, and the `main` merge them. It looks like this:

```
def worker() :
    s = set()
    # add millions of elements to s
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool( processes=20 )
    fullSet = set.union( * pool.imap_unordered( worker, xrange(100) ) )
    pool.close() # This takes a LOT OF TIME!
    pool.join()
```

As I said, the `pool.close()` might take 5, 10 min or more to return. Same problem occurs when using dictionaries instead of sets. This is what the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) says about `close`:

> Prevents any more tasks from being submitted to the pool. Once all the
>   tasks have been completed the worker processes will exit.

I guess I don't understand what's going on. After the line `fullSet = ...`, all the work is done and I don't need the workers anymore. What are they doing that is taking so much time?

Comment: That is the documentation for [`multiprocessing.Queue.close`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.close) not [`multiprocessing.Pool.close`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.close)

Comment: @behzad.nouri You're right, I corrected the quote. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's the `close()` line that's taking a long time? `pool.close` just sets a couple of instance variables on the `Pool` object. There's nothing going on in there that could take a long time under any circumstances.

Comment: I agree with dano. It makes more sense that `join` blocks your application—because that is the primary purpose of `join`—and you just think it’s `close` instead. Add some debug prints between the commands, to see what’s actually being executed when.

Comment: @usualme In general you shouldn't use the `processes` argument when creating a `Pool`. By default it will create as many processes as your CPU has cores/hardware threads. Using more reduces performance.

Comment: @usualme You should probably use `map` instead of `imap_unordered` here. The main advantage of `imap_unordered` is that you can get results back as they complete, at the cost of slower IPC because items aren't sent in chunks between processes. But you're waiting for all the results before using them anyway, so you're just getting slower IPC with none of the benefits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very unlikely that [`Pool.close`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.close) is taking that long. Simply because this is [the source of `close`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/50722d2f08c7/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l446)

```
def close(self):
    debug('closing pool')
    if self._state == RUN:
        self._state = CLOSE
        self._worker_handler._state = CLOSE
```

So all that’s happening is that some state variables are changed. This has no measurable impact on the runtime of that method and will not cause it to return later. You could just assume `close` to return *instantaneously*.

Now instead, what’s way more likely is that your `pool.join()` line is the “culprit” of this delay. But it’s just doing [its job](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.join):

> Wait for the worker processes to exit.

It essentially calls [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) on every process in the pool. And if you are joining a process or thread, you are *actively waiting* for it to complete its work and terminate.

So in your case, you have 20 processes running that add a million elements to a set. That takes a while. To make your main process not quit early (causing child processes to die btw.), you are waiting for the worker processes to finish their work; by joining on them. So what you’re experiencing is likely what should happen for the amount of work you do.

On a side note: If you do heavy CPU work in your worker functions, you shouldn’t spawn more processes than your CPU has hardware threads available, as you will only introduce additional overhead from managing and switching processes. For example for a consumer Core i7, this number would be 8.

Comment: Shouldn't all the workers have finished when `* pool.imap_unordered` has unpacked all the results?

Comment: @RolandSmith Yes. By the time `join` is reached all the workers will already be completed. So `join` shouldn't be blocking, either.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the iteration over the result of `pool.imap_unordered` and the subsequent `set.union` that take a long time.

After each worker has finished building a set, it has to be pickled, sent back to the original process and unpickled. This takes time and memory. And then the `*` has to unpack all the sets for `union` to process.

You might get better results with `map_async`. Have the callback append the returned set to a list, and loop over that list using `union` on each set.